# Angular - Add menu click event Component as a Page which is used as a dialog box inside another component

Tags: angular, html, navbar

I have used a component as a Dialog Box in another component page. But now I need to use that same Dialog box as a page to menu click event.

When try to do that, it gives me this error----

```
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CopyImplementDialogComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CopyImplementDialogComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CopyImplementDialogComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CopyImplementDialogComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
    at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12619)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

this is navBar Code.

```
                {
                    icon: 'file_copy',
                    text: 'Copy Implement',
                    type: NavType.RouterLink,
                    location: 'copy/implement'
                },
```

this is router.ts

```
{
        path: 'copy/implement',
        component: CopyImplementDialogComponent
},
```

this is my app.Modeule.ts

```
import { CopyImplementDialogComponent } from './setup-implement/copy-implement-dialog/copy-implement-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'

@NgModule({
    entryComponents: [
        ImplementStatusModalComponent,
        AttachImplementModalComponent,
        RemoveImplementModalComponent,
        RecordRepairModalComponent,
        RecordReplaceModalComponent,
        ChangeImplementJobsiteModalComponent,
        AddRepairerWorkshopModalComponent,
        SchematicViewComponent,
        DeleteConfirmationDialogComponent
    ],
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavbarTopComponent,
      NavbarSide,
      BreadCrumbTopComponent,
      RedirectComponent,
      DashboardComponent,
      ImplementDetailsComponent,
      ImplementStatusModalComponent,
      AttachImplementModalComponent,
      RemoveImplementModalComponent,
      RecordRepairModalComponent,
      RecordReplaceModalComponent,
      ChangeImplementJobsiteModalComponent,
      RemoveImplementModalComponent,
      ImplementTemplateSetupComponent,
      AddRepairerWorkshopModalComponent,
      FilterPipe,
      ImplementTemplatesComponent,
      SchematicViewComponent,
      CarouselComponent,
      CarouselItemDirective,
      CarouselItemElement,
      SetupEquipmentComponent,
      SetupImplementComponent,
      ApplySelectionComponent,
      DraggableSchematicComponent,
      DeleteConfirmationDialogComponent,
      PreferencesComponent,
      CopyImplementDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
      routing,
      BrowserModule,
      HttpModule,
      FormsModule,
      MaterialModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatDialogModule, 
      HttpClientModule,
      ToastModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
      AppService,
      ImplementDetailsService,
      ChangeImplementJobsiteModalService,
      AttachImplementModalService,
      RemoveImplementModalService,
      ImplementStatusModalService,
      InventoryService,
      CustomerService,
      EquipmentService,
      ImplementTemplateService,
      UserService,
      SchematicViewService,
      SetupEquipmentService,
      SetupImplementService,
      PreferencesService
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi, have you check your module? If these 2 Components (The injected component inside the dialog box and the dialog box component itself) are in the app.module?

Or, if you are using it from another module. Make sure those components are in the "exports" property from their respective module.

Comment: i am trying to use same CopyImplementDialogComponent for both as a page and a dialogbox. I have update my question with my app module.ts
and I have add my component in declaration of the app modeule.ts
CopyImplementDialogComponent

Comment: I think the issue here is your MatDialogRef from angular/material. Try to refer on this thread I saw on github. I hope this helps. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8419